# How to use QtStateMachine on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, qt

I want to use [QtStateMachine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtstatemachine-index.html) in one of my projects.

But I fail to find the right package to install it.

There is a package [qt6-examples](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/qt6-examples/), which provides example code for the `QtStateMachine` module, but I cannot build them because `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: statemachine`.

Frankly speaking, I cannot believe there is a (GPL3) Qt-Module not available in Pacman, not even as AUR.

Am I overlooking something? How am I supposed to use `QtStateMachine`? Do I need to compile it myself? Has anyone used `QtStateMachine` with other package managers?

<sup>There is [libqt6statemachine6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/libqt6statemachine6) for Ubuntu, though it doesn't seem to be a dev package (missing headers, CMake-stuff and `-dev` suffix).</sup>

I forgot to mention that I need the Qt6 package.
[qt5-base](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt5-base/) contains QtStateMachine, but I need Qt6.

Answer (score 0):

It's in [qt6-scxml](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/qt6-scxml/).

You can find the package via guessing what files it should provide:

`pkgfile -sri statemachine`

- `-s` is for search
- `-r` is for regex (i.e., no full match required)
- `-i` is for case insensitive.

Make sure to update `pkgfile` first: `sudo pkgfile -u`.

This yields four packages containing qt6 in the name, so it's easy to use https://archlinux.org/packages/ to guess the right one.